# Why is my Edit Function Showing all Column entries?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a webapp that calls on a SQL Query for a list of applications impacted by a project.  I want my admins to be able to click edit and add remove applications to this list at will.  Currently when they click edit they see every single Application that is Impacted by ANY project as part of the list box even though in the Gridview they only see the Applications Impacted by that specific project.  When I hard code the value for the project it works, but I need it to be a variable depending on which project my admins click on to edit.

```
select 
    Applications.ApplicationName, 
    Projects.ProjectName 
from ImpactedApplications 
inner join  Applications 
    on ImpactedApplications.AppId=Applications.AppId
inner join Projects 
    on ImpactedApplications.ProjectId=Projects.ProjectId
Where Projects.ProjectId=57 <--This is Hardcoded.  I need this to be dynamic.
```

Adding Code

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ImpactedApplications">
 <EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ImpactedApps" 
  DataTextField="ApplicationName" DataValueField="ProjectName" Width="250px"></asp:ListBox>
  &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" />
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Remove" />
 <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox3" runat="server" DataSourceID="Applications" 
  DataTextField="ApplicationName" DataValueField="AppId" Width="250px">
 </asp:ListBox>
 <br />
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ImpactedApps" runat="server" 


 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LandscapeServicesConnectionString %>" 
 SelectCommand="select Applications.ApplicationName, Projects.ProjectName 
from ImpactedApplications 
inner join  Applications 
on ImpactedApplications.AppId=Applications.AppId
inner join Projects 
on ImpactedApplications.ProjectId=Projects.ProjectId
where Projects.ProjectName=@Projectname">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="PO Consolidation (EDW)" 
FormField="Gridview1 - Column[2] - Project Name" Name="Project Name" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Adding Background Code

```
public partial class Update : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string query { get; set; }
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LandscapeServicesConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

    }


    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a *parameterized* query:

```
select 
    Applications.ApplicationName, 
    Projects.ProjectName 
from ImpactedApplications 
inner join  Applications 
    on ImpactedApplications.AppId=Applications.AppId
inner join Projects 
    on ImpactedApplications.ProjectId=Projects.ProjectId
where Projects.ProjectId=@projectId
```

Then when you create your `SqlCommand` add a parameter and give it the value from your form:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectId",projectId);
```

Comment: Okay I think I follow what you are suggesting.  Two questions.  For the parameter Im assuming you mean the column name of my form? And Second  Where do I add the cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectId",projectId);

Comment: It doesn't have to be the same name - and you add the parameter after you create the `SqlCommand`.  If you post the code you use to execute the query I can be more specific.

Comment: Hi there I added the code to the original post.  Thank you so much.